# How do I run my package's tests using different versions of its prerequisites?

Tags: testing, haskell, integration-testing, cabal

Suppose I've written a Haskell package that I'd like to release to Hackage.

Suppose I've written automated tests for it, so I know it works on my machine, with the version of GHC I have installed, and the versions of other packages it depends on that I have installed.

Is there an automated way of running my package's tests using other versions of packages it depends on, and other versions of GHC (and versions of Hugs, etc)?

The objective is not only to check that it works with the prerequisites I think it should work with, but also to confirm it doesn't work with versions I expect it not to work with.

Comment: If I understand your question right, you could write separate `.cabal` files in different folders which refer to the same source-folders but with different build-requirement

Comment: @hvr Sure, but is there already a tool to write those `.cabal` files for me?

Comment: Solving this exact problem is exactly what a wanted to do sometime. It would be the first step in an automated Haskell build system I would think and a useful tool for the whole community. You should look at 'packdeps' because it does similar stuff with package checking but not this like we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for now your best bet is [cabal-dev](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev) or [capri](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/capri) and some homegrown scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cabal configure --preference=DEPENDENCY`, as described by `cabal configure --help`. I don't know, how it work, maybe just try it out. For instance, to test with the old base package, try

```
cabal configure "--preference=base==3.0.0"
```

You may put the combinations of dependecies you want to test into some shell script, however you like.